# Creating A Dropdown Search Bar For The NavBar

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger

I would like help in coding a dropdown search bar that appears on my hovering navigation bar. An example of such an element can be viewed on the following blog - http://www.theprivatelifeofagirl.com/ - in the top right hand side corner of the navbar.

I have a search bar already coded in my own navbar however I would like for only the small "search icon" to be visible and for the reader to be able to click the icon and for a search bar to drop down, in which the reader would then be able to type of they're searching for. I have included the relevant html and css coding for the search bar below :

```
<style>
#search {
   text-align: left;
   margin-right: -7%;
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   max-width: 210px;
   border: 0;
 }
 #searchform {
   height: 20px;
 }
 #search #s {
   background: #f5f5f5 url(http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/829C0943-C2A2-4052-BFF5-49E6606F44B6_zps3r9lpyvb.gif)98% 50% no-repeat;
   color: #494949;
   background-size: 15px;
   font-size: 10.5px!important;
   font-family: karla, arial;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: normal;
   letter-spacing: 0.09em;
   border: 0;
   width: 60%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   outline: none;
   position: relative;
   top: 18px;
   padding-left: 6px;
 }
.searchborder {
border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
right: 10px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 50px;
}
</style>

<div class='searchborder'>
<div id='search' title='Type and hit enter'>
<form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get'>
<input id='s' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;)    {this.value = &quot;Search&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Search&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Search'/>
 </form>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
   </div>
```

Any input in this matter would be greatly appreciated. The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

Comment: You could use js to achieve this. You create an event when you click on that icon that change your css, making your search form dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";
$('#top-search a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.show-search').slideToggle('fast');
});
});
//]]></script>

<div id='top-search'>
<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>
</div>
<div class='show-search'>
<form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get' role='search'>
<div>
<input id='s' name='q' placeholder='Search and hit enter...' type='text'/>
</div>
</form>
```

This is used in the website you showed.

Edit:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/n6Lj13qr/)

It's not exactly the same as on your website, but it's working and you can style and change it to work with your website :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer chris. Apologies, however, I'm not very knowledgeable html and code language. I'm unable to get my desired affect with the code you have provided. Perhaps Im doing something incorrect

Comment: Perhaps you can give a link to your website or you can create a jsfiddle so I can apply it there :). Also, did you include http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js in your header? This is required for the js to work :)

Comment: I wasn't aware that I was suppose to add that piece of coding. I don't have much knowledge on HTML. I'd appreciate it if you would give me exact instructions. Also the URL to the site is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

Comment: My mistake, you don't need to add it. I updated my post with a working JSFiddle you can use as a basis.

Comment: I'm having such an awful time customising this. I've tried various different pieces of coding however I'm unable to get achieve the look I want for the search bar. Any help in creating a dropdown search bar and customising it with an image would be greatly appreciated.